# Initialize array or vector over constructor's initializing list

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, constructor, initialization

How can I initialize a (string) array or vector with a constructor's initializing list in C++?

Consider please this example where I want to initialize a string array with arguments given to the constructor:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Myclass{
           private:
           std::string commands[2];
           // std::vector<std::string> commands(2); respectively 

           public:
           MyClass( std::string command1, std::string command2) : commands( ??? )
           {/* */}
}

int main(){
          MyClass myclass("foo", "bar");
          return 0;
}
```

Besides that, which of the two types (array vs vector) is recommended for saving two strings while creating an object, and why?

Comment: Use braces, just like you normally would.

Comment: @chris: As in `Myclass m = {"hello", "world"};` or as in `Myclass(const std::string& c1, const std::string& c2) : commands{c1, c2}{}`?

Comment: @thokra, One of those won't initialize the members, while the other is displayed nicely in Vaughn's answer.

Comment: @chris: Yes, that was sort of what I was getting at. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With C++11, you do it like this:

```
class MyClass{
           private:
           std::string commands[2];
           //std::vector<std::string> commands;

           public:
           MyClass( std::string command1, std::string command2)
             : commands{command1,command2}
           {/* */}
};
```

For pre-C++11 compilers, you will need to initialize the array or vector in the body of the constructor:

```
class MyClass{
           private:
           std::string commands[2];

           public:
           MyClass( std::string command1, std::string command2)
           {
               commands[0] = command1;
               commands[1] = command2;
           }
};
```

or

```
class MyClass{
           private:
           std::vector<std::string> commands;

           public:
           MyClass( std::string command1, std::string command2)
           {
               commands.reserve(2);
               commands.push_back(command1);
               commands.push_back(command2);
           }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. And for older compilers?

Comment: @fotinsky: I've extended my answer to cover pre-C++11 compilers.

Comment: @VaughnCato, what if I use C++11 compilers and define a private member `std::vector<std::string> commands;` as you did in the pre-C++ example? Is there a faster way to initialize `commands`?

Comment: @leofang yes. It's exactly the same either way.

Answer (score 1):

In the initializer list you may call any constructor of the class of the member you want to initialize. Take a look at `std::string` and `std::vector` documentation and choose the constructor that works for you.

For storing two objects I would recommend using `std::pair`. However if you expect that the number may grow `std::vector` is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
#include <utility>

...
std::pair<string, string> commands;
commands=std::make_pair("string1","string2");

...
//to access them use
std::cout<<commands.first<<" "<<commands.second;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Myclass{
private:
    Vector<string> *commands;
    // std::vector<std::string> commands(2); respectively 

    public:
    MyClass( std::string command1, std::string command2)
    {
        commands.append(command1);  //Add your values here
    }
}
```